# Abaqus Scripting: Error on code to create a set of vertices from several instances

Tags: python, abaqus

Here is the error I am getting when trying to define set of vertices through Python script

[image: 1]

```
mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.Set(name='Set-3', vertices=
    mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.instances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+''+'1'].vertices.findAt((75.0, 125.0, 0))+\
    mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.instances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'2'].vertices.findAt((75, 125, 35), )+\
    mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.instances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'3'].vertices.findAt((75, 125, 30), )+\
    mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.instances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'4'].vertices.findAt((75, 125, 25), )+\
    mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.instances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'5'].vertices.findAt((75, 125, 20), )+\
    mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.instances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'6'].vertices.findAt((75, 125, 15), )+\
    mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.instances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'7'].vertices.findAt((75, 125, 10), )+\
    mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.instances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'8'].vertices.findAt((75, 125, 5), ))
```

Above is the code I am trying to use to define the set. I double checked that all the coordinates are corresponding to where those vertices are located for each of the instance. The code above was adapted from that in the journal file as shown below. What I did was changing the `.getSequenceFromMask(mask=('[#1 ]', ), )` to `.findAt((X, Y, Z), )`, where X, Y & Z correspond to the coordinate of vertex of interest. The error looks like Abaqus doesn't use "+" in defining set of vertices however that was what spat out from the journal file where I adapted my code from.

```
mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.Set(name='Set-2', vertices=
    mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.instances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'1'].vertices.getSequenceFromMask(mask=('[#1 ]', ), )+\
    mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.instances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'2'].vertices.getSequenceFromMask(mask=('[#1 ]', ), )+\
    mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.instances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'3'].vertices.getSequenceFromMask(mask=('[#1 ]', ), )+\
    mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.instances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'4'].vertices.getSequenceFromMask(mask=('[#1 ]', ), )+\
    mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.instances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'5'].vertices.getSequenceFromMask(mask=('[#1 ]', ), )+\
    mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.instances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'6'].vertices.getSequenceFromMask(mask=('[#1 ]', ), )+\
    mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.instances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'7'].vertices.getSequenceFromMask(mask=('[#1 ]', ), )+\
    mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.instances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'8'].vertices.getSequenceFromMask(mask=('[#1 ]', ), ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to go around this. It seems like Abaqus only like the `getSequenceFromMask()` method when it comes to defining set. Selecting vertices by `findAt()` method works fine in other cases but not in defining set. So the workaround is to convert the coordinates of the vertices of interest into a series of "click" (i.e. just like how it was defined in Abaqus GUI) at the exact location of the vertices. Below is the snippet that will do the job. There are 8 vertices grouped in 1 set. `v` select the vertex, `vi` (where `i = 1, 2, 3, ...`) "click" the vertex selected in `v` to add it to the set.

```
myInstances = mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.instances

v=myInstances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'1'].vertices.getClosest(coordinates=(((75, 125, 0)),))
v1=myInstances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'1'].vertices.findAt((((v[0][1])),))
v=myInstances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'2'].vertices.getClosest(coordinates=(((75, 125, 35)),))
v2=myInstances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'2'].vertices.findAt((((v[0][1])),))
v=myInstances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'3'].vertices.getClosest(coordinates=(((75, 125, 30)),))
v3=myInstances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'3'].vertices.findAt((((v[0][1])),))
v=myInstances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'4'].vertices.getClosest(coordinates=(((75, 125, 25)),))
v4=myInstances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'4'].vertices.findAt((((v[0][1])),))
v=myInstances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'5'].vertices.getClosest(coordinates=(((75, 125, 20)),))
v5=myInstances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'5'].vertices.findAt((((v[0][1])),))
v=myInstances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'6'].vertices.getClosest(coordinates=(((75, 125, 15)),))
v6=myInstances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'6'].vertices.findAt((((v[0][1])),))
v=myInstances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'7'].vertices.getClosest(coordinates=(((75, 125, 10)),))
v7=myInstances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'7'].vertices.findAt((((v[0][1])),))
v=myInstances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'8'].vertices.getClosest(coordinates=(((75, 125, 5)),))
v8=myInstances[myModule+'_'+myRigidBeamName+'-'+'8'].vertices.findAt((((v[0][1])),))

mdb.models['Model-8'].rootAssembly.Set(name='Set-4', vertices=v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).